# Compiler warnings with enum constants

Tags: java

I am having difficulty using generics with `enum` constants. I'm getting the compiler warning:

> Unchecked call to 'handle(M)' as a member of raw type 'Test.MessageHandler'

on the last line of the snippet below.

Any hints on how to remove this warning so would be highly appreciated.

```
public class Test {
    private enum MessageNumber {
        LOGIN,
        LOGOUT
    }

    private interface Message {}
    private static class LoginMessage implements Message {}
    private static class LogoutMessage implements Message {}

    private interface MessageHandler<M extends Message> {
        void handle(M msg);
    }

    private static class LoginMessageHandler implements MessageHandler<LoginMessage> {
        public void handle(LoginMessage msg) {System.out.println(msg);}
    }
    private static class LogoutMessageHandler implements MessageHandler<LogoutMessage> {
        public void handle(LogoutMessage msg) {System.out.println(msg);}
    }

    private static final Map<MessageNumber, MessageHandler> HANDLERS = new ConcurrentHashMap<MessageNumber, MessageHandler>() {{
        put(MessageNumber.LOGIN, new LoginMessageHandler());
        put(MessageNumber.LOGOUT, new LogoutMessageHandler());
    }};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessageHandler loginHandler = HANDLERS.get(MessageNumber.LOGIN);
        loginHandler.handle(new LoginMessage()); //Compiler warning: Unchecked call to 'handle(M)' as a member of raw type 'Test.MessageHandler'
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the limitations of Java enums is that you can't have per-value generic types. It's unchecked because you have a raw `MessageHandler` - you could equally have written `HANDLERS.get(MessageNumber.LOGOUT)` on the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `loginHandler` as a *raw* type - ie untyped:

```
MessageHandler loginHandler = HANDLERS.get(MessageNumber.LOGIN);
```

Instead, type the variable for logins, and add a cast:

```
MessageHandler<LoginMessage> loginHandler = 
    (MessageHandler<LoginMessage>)HANDLERS.get(MessageNumber.LOGIN);
```

You'll still get a warning though, just on a different line.

Comment: Wouldn't work with `LoginMessage`, at least without an unchecked cast - you'd have to make `HANDLERS` non-raw as well, and that would need to use `MessageHandler<?>` as the value type.

Comment: @Andy yeah - I have been typing that up. Note that the map doesn't have to be non-raw - there is a bit of generics kung fu to deal with that. See update

Comment: @ruakh oops... I was thinking of nested generics. You're right. KISS.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious part is that you get the warning because you didn't specify type parameter for `MessageHandler` in `HANDLERS` map.

But if you try to specify it you'll end up with `Map<MessageNumber, MessageHandler<? extends Message>>`, and then you won't be able to call `handle()` without doing an unchecked cast.

What this all is telling you is that **Java cannot check the correctness of your type cast *statically***.

What you can do is perform the check at run time. If you want to check the cast yourself rather than allowing the code to possibly trigger a `ClassCastException`, you could do something like this:

```
private interface MessageHandler {
    void handle(Message msg);
}

private static class TypedMessageHandler<M extends Message> {
    private final Class<M> clazz;

    public TypedMessageHandler(M clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void handle(Message msg) {
        if (msg == null || clazz.isAssignableFrom(msg.getClass()) {
            handleInternal((M) msg);
        } else {
            // your error logic
        }
    }

    abstract protected void handleInternal(M msg);
}

private static class LoginMessageHandler extends TypedMessageHandler<LoginMessage> {

    public LoginMessageHandler() {
        super(LoginMessage.class);
    }

    protected void handleInternal(LoginMessage msg) {System.out.println(msg);}
}

private static class LogoutMessageHandler extends TypedMessageHandler<LogoutMessage> {

    public LogoutMessageHandler () {
        super(LogoutMessage.class);
    }

    protected void handleInternal(LogoutMessage msg) {System.out.println(msg);}
}
```